Prove $X \cong Ker(e) \oplus Ker(1_X-e)$ in abelian K-category
In abelian $K$-category $\mathcal{C}$, we have an object $X$
and an idempotent $e\in End_{\mathcal{C}}(X)$ satisfy
(1) $e^2 = e$;
(2)$(1_X-e)^2=(1_X-e)$;
(3) $e(1_X-e)=(1_X-e)e=0_X$.
I want to show $X \cong Ker(e) \oplus Ker(1_X-e)$.
If you have answer or reference, thank you in advance.
.
.
.
(definition of abelian $K$-category $\mathcal{C}$ here)


$Hom_\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ has $K$-vector space structure, $K$
is a field, composition map $Hom_\mathcal{C}(X,Y)\times Hom_\mathcal{C}(Y,Z) \to Hom_\mathcal{C}(X,Z)$ is bilinear.




$\mathcal{C}$ admit null object $0$, finite product and coproduct, kernel and cokernel.




Has canonical isomorphism from $\text{coker} \ker f$ to $\ker \text{coker} f$.



Let $A\in\mathcal{C}$ be arbitrary. We have a map $$\theta_A\colon\mathcal{C}(A,X)\to\mathcal{C}(A,\mathrm{ker}(e)\oplus\mathrm{ker}(1_X-e)),f\mapsto ((1_X-e)f,ef)$$ which is natural in $A$, and writing $i_e\colon\mathrm{ker}(e)\to X$ and $i_{1_X-e}\colon\mathrm{ker}(1_X-e)\to X$ for the canonical maps, another map $$\zeta_A\colon\mathcal{C}(A,\mathrm{ker}(e)\oplus\mathrm{ker}(1_X-e))\to\mathcal{C}(A,X),(g,h)\mapsto i_eg+i_{1_X-e}h$$ which is also natural in $A$. It is clear that $\zeta_A\theta_A(f)=f$ for any $f\colon A\to X$. Conversely, given $(g,h)\colon A\to\mathrm{ker}(e)\oplus\mathrm{ker}(1_X-e)$, we have $(1_X-e)(i_eg+i_{1_X-e}h)=(1_X-e)i_eg+0=1_Xi_eg-0=i_eg$, and considered as a map with codomain $\mathrm{ker}(e)$ this is just $g$. Likewise, $e(i_eg+i_{1_X-e}h)=h$ when considered as a map with codomain $\mathrm{ker}(1_X-e)$. This proves $\theta_A\zeta_A(g,h)=(g,h)$. Hence we have found a natural isomorphism $$
\mathcal{C}(-,X)\cong\mathcal{C}(-,\mathrm{ker}(e)\oplus\mathrm{ker}(1_X-e)).$$ We conclude by the Yoneda lemma.
